# Perfectly center content of element with border and box-sizing

Tags: html, css, centering, border-box

I set up a circular div with a circle inside using a html entity ⬤, the div is 20px wide and high and has a 2px border and `box-sizing: border-box` to stop the size fron increasing.

Typically to fill the whole div with the circle I'd also set the circle's `font-size` and `line-height` to 20px, but since 4px of the div is now taken up with border I set the line-height to 16px. This accounted for the vertical centering but the horizontal centering is still off.

**How can I center it perfectly?**

https://jsfiddle.net/3drve2xn/

```
 div{
   border: 2px solid #C15649;
   line-height:16px;
   font-size:20px;
   width:20px;
   height:20px;
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   left:0;
   z-index: 1;
   text-align: center;
   color:black;
   border-radius: 50%;
   content:"\002B24";
   cursor: pointer;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Like that: https://jsfiddle.net/3drve2xn/1/ ?

Comment: Border-box on everything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

does the output you look for look like this try to check it this fiddle and let me know if you still need more changes.

```css
 div {
   border: 2px solid #C15649;
   width:20px;
   height:20px;
   position: relative;
   top:0;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   left:0;
   z-index: 1;
   text-align: center;
   color:black;
   border-radius: 50%;
   cursor: pointer;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
div:before{
 position: absolute;
 content:"";
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 background:black;
 border-radius:50%;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 margin:auto;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think **putting a border around a character** is exactly possible in CSS because it heavily depends on the *character* and the *font*.

So here are your options AFAIK:

**Option 1**:

This is a *not-so-good option*- wrap the character inside another element and put border to the outer element. Adjust the border for the font-size that you have given.

Here is an example:

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid #C15649;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div span {
  line-height: 46px;
  font-size: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  content: "\002B24";
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: -3px;
  top: -2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>&#11044;</span>
</div>
```

**Option 2**:

If a border to the character is what you desire, you can use `text-shadow`:

(note that `text-shadow` is supported in IE 10+ only)

```css
div {
  /*border: 2px solid #C15649;*/
  text-shadow: -2px 0 red, 0 2px red, 2px 0 red, 0 -2px red;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
  content: "\002B24";
}
```

```html
<div>&#11044;</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't really state my intended outcome. It isn't to put a border on the entity exactly, it is supposed to look a bit like a radio button. So in the end the inner circle will be smaller I just made it the same size so it's be easy to see centering discrepancies. This is a helpful answer thought to give me optins.

Comment: Well, in that case you would have to drop the idea of using ⬤ and adopt @RaniMorelesRubillos 's answer :)